# MSBuild and VS 2013 have different outputs

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, msbuild

I've built a C# library in VS 2013. The library is supposed to get picked up and run by another program our company maintains. When I build the library (Debug or Release) myself, the company program picks it up just fine. However, when I build the library using ABS (MSBuild) the company program can't find my library or something like that; It throws a `MissingMethodException`.

I can't figure out what the difference(s) between the VS 2013 and ABS builds. Also, from what I understand VS 2013 incorporates ABS in a Build Studio tab, but I get an unimplemented exception whenever I try to add the build script I'm using.

How do I figure out what's causing the difference in the outputs? Optionally, how do I get Build Studio in VS 2013 to work?

**Update**
I've tried cross-examining the log files from each program. One of the notable differences is Visual Studio 2013 is using "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin" in place of "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319", a value ABS calls CscToolPath. I've been looking for a way to change the CscToolPath, but I can't find anything on it. How can I change this value? More importantly, will it solve my problem?

**Update**
I've uploaded the diagnostics from [Visual Studio 2013](http://expirebox.com/download/e2b533788573cd715a823e2c00b836b9.html) and [Automated Build Studio](http://expirebox.com/download/0bc8f869aa44ff9dadbde987bd17233a.html) to EmpireBox. You can download the files for the next 48 hours ('til 12/5/2014 a bit before 1 o'clock). Let me know if you need the links refreshed.

Comment: An error message might be helpful...

Comment: It's not: `System.MissingMethodException: Method 'PaymentNotification.RunApps.RunBatch' not found.
   at System.RuntimeType.InvokeMember(String name, BindingFlags bindingFlags, Binder binder, Object target, Object[] providedArgs, ParameterModifier[] modifiers, CultureInfo culture, String[] namedParams)
   at SelectHealth.Batch.BatchJob.Execute()`. This is the first and only error message. What I've deduced is more useful. Unless you wanted the Build Studio error message: `The operation could not be completed. Not implemented`

Comment: When you **run from yourself**, do you have all DLLs at the same folder? What about when you run after a MSBuild? Does all DLLs come along?

Comment: Yes, yes, yes. Albeit, some of the DLLs that get copied are in the GAC. They shouldn't be included, so I exclude those. Including them makes no difference.

Comment: @ricksmt Would you please post the msbuild parameters you are using? You can set the VS Build to output all the parameters it sets, so you can use the same. Might be it is building to a different target/framework, so the library dlls do not apply anymore. The library is using the same MSBuild?

Comment: @rodrigogq See the update. The target and framework are the same. It seems different versions/toolsets might be being used. The logs indicate toolset 12.0 is being used, but the paths (as indicated) are different.

Comment: @ricksmt Try building your library in x86 and use your ABS build again. You might be compiling in another architecture.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65986/discussion-between-ricksmt-and-rodrigogq).

Comment: The suggestion from the error is that while the broken build finds a copy of your DLL, at runtime it's trying to use an outdated version which is missing some methods expected by the code. One thing you might try is to use Fusion Log Viewer to see where the assembly binds are happening during your build (and specifically during the invocation of BatchJob.Execute() (is this a post-build step?). Maybe the post-build step runs slightly differently within Visual Studio. FWIW you can ramp up the verbosity of VS build logs to get more diagnostics and compare with MSBuild.

Comment: @StephenConnolly I'll check out Fusion Log Viewer. BatchJob.Execute() is a line in the stand-alone company program where it tries to call code in my library. The exception you're referencing occurs outside the build. And I've tried comparing logs; See the update--know anything about CscToolPath?

Comment: Hi, do you know what are the environment vars your ABS (is it stand for automatic build system)  is using when builds your solution ? It'd be great to see diagnostics output from your build server and from your visual studio. Another option worth to validate is - try to build your dll locally, but not in visual studio - just call MSBuild directly on the solution or even better - exact dll project (with /verbosity:detailed or even diag switch) and post your logs here\link them from pastebin. Verify whether error still exists or not when you build your dll locally.

Comment: CscToolPath is one of common properties - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb629394.aspx. I don't think it's a good idea to play with it unless you 100% sure that it's the cause of the problem.